# Adding SQL Queries in For Loop in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, postgresql

Is there a way to add SQL queries in a For Loop in python where the table names and database names are variable?
Something like this:

```py
database = []
tables= []
column = []

for x in database: 
    for y in tables:
        for z in column:
            SQL = "select * from x.y where z is NOT NULL;"
            cursor.execute(sql)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Yes, this should be possible, at least in theory.  What is your actual question?

Comment: ...although this kind of problem can be symptomatic of poorly designed databases/tables/columns

Comment: Yes its possible. For examples, Check out this python sqlite documentation. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use string formatting. In your example:

```
database = []
tables= []
column = []

for x in database: 
    for y in tables:
        for z in column:
            SQL = "select * from {x}.{y} where {z} is NOT NULL;".format(x=x, y=y, z=z)
            cursor.execute(sql)
```

It's a single example of python string formatting, but you either can use string concatenation, `% formatting` or `f-strings`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.format()` method of string object to get the sql query string:

```
SQL = "select * from {}.{} where {} is NOT NULL;".format(x, y, z)
```

Or append values like this:

```
SQL = "select * from " + str(x) + "." + str(y) + " where " + str(z) + " is NOT NULL;"
```

I recommend the first solution.

Comment: Both methods worked great especially the first one, thank you!